# Python requests ajax form authentication issue

Tags: python, ajax, powershell, web-scraping, forms-authentication

I have seemed to be an obvious problem, login to a website programmatically and then get data when authenticated.

I've been reading StackOverflow for a few days and can't find a working solution.

Here is the login form, which is also accessible using a separate URL and after logging in via browser it redirects to the home page:

```
<strong class="popup-title">i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>Login</strong>
<div class="popup-holder">
    <form action="https://test.com/login/" data-form="ajax" method="post">
        <div class="generic-error hidden">
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="login_username" class="field-label required">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="login_username" class="textfield"
                    placeholder="Enter your username" />
                <div class="field-error down"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <label for="login_pass" class="field-label required">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="pass" id="login_pass" class="textfield" placeholder="Enter your password" />
                <div class="field-error down"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left: 0;">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="login_remember_me" class="checkbox" value="1" checked />
                    <label for="login_remember_me">remember me</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5 forgot pull-right" style="padding-right: 0px;">
                    <a href="https://test.com/reset-password/" data-fancybox="ajax">Forgot password?</a><br />
                    <a href="https://test.com/resend-confirmation/" data-fancybox="ajax">Missing confirmation email?</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login" />
                <input type="hidden" name="email_link" value="https://test.com/email/" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" value="Log in" />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <span class="form-separator">Not a member yet? Sign up now for free!</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <a href="https://test.com/signup/" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" data-fancybox="ajax">Sign up</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the Python code I've tried:

```
payload = {
   'username': 'mylogin',
   'pass': 'mypass'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post('https://test.com/login/', data=payload)
    r = s.get('https://test.com/testpage/')
```

Same logic in PowerShell:

```
$payload = @{
   username = 'mylogin'
   pass = 'mypass'
}

$r = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://test.com/login/' -Method POST -Body $payload -SessionVariable 'Session'
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://test.com/testpage/" -WebSession $Session
```

But none of the above is working, I'm still getting results for non-authenticated user.

Comment: Does the web server use session cookies that need being returned when login?

Comment: Yes, from what I see in Postman, there are two cookies after issues get request to the login form:
PHPSESSID=48947532f789fd83711946b87d07a309; Path=/; Domain=test.com; Secure;
kt_ips=178.137.7.23; Path=/; Domain=test.com; Secure; Expires=Fri, 17 Dec 2021 11:59:10 GMT;

Comment: Well, then you need to return those cookies with your POST requests: `cookies = {'PHPSESSID': '48947532f789fd83711946b87d07a309'}  
r = requests.post(''https://test.com/login/, cookies=cookies, data=payload)`. But you need to issue a GET request first in order to get the actual cookie value.

Comment: Tried different ways, using Session and without it, seems to me, using it is more convenient, as in theory cookies and headers should be set automatically, so I don't have to set them manually. But anyway, just tried getting the page, extracting cookies value, then sending back with a post and subsequent get method, but still getting results for an unauthenticated user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example using one of my Django sites and a demo login account.

`requests.Session()` is used to manage the cookies. In order to make it work, I had to explicitely manage the header content such as adding the `Referer` before posting the login.

```
import requests
import re

base_url = 'https://www.archery-analytics.com/en/'

# use session object to manage cookies and headers
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update({
    'Host': 'www.archery-analytics.com',
    'Origin': 'https://www.archery-analytics.com',
    })

# get login form and cookies
r1 = s.get(base_url + 'public/home')
print(r1.status_code, r1.url)

# add Referer to header
s.headers.update({
    'Referer': r1.url,
    })

# get csrf token of form (= hidden input element of login form)
reggie = re.compile(rb".*name=\"csrfmiddlewaretoken\" value=\"(?P<csrf>\w+)\".*")
match = reggie.findall(r1.content)

# login data for demo account
payload = {
    'username': 'RyngDyng',
    'password': '123demo123',
    'login': '',
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': match[0].decode("utf-8")
}

# login post
r2 = s.post(base_url + 'global/login', data=payload)
print(r2.status_code, r2.url)

# check successful login
if r2.status_code == requests.codes.ok:

    # test logged in: access to page for editing user profile
    r3 = s.get(base_url + 'global/edit_profile')
    print(r3.status_code, r3.url)
    
    
    # logout
    r4 = s.get(base_url + 'global/logout')
    print(r4.status_code, r4.url)
```

Output:

```
200 https://www.archery-analytics.com/en/public/home
200 https://www.archery-analytics.com/en/public/home
200 https://www.archery-analytics.com/en/global/edit_profile
200 https://www.archery-analytics.com/en/public/home
```

Comment: Just tried - not working(

Comment: I would recommend to analyze the HTTP headers of a successful login using a browser, and then do a `r = requests.post(...)` and compare the headers `r.request.headers` with the successful login headers. Then, update the headers to make them equal (like in my example above with the Referer).

Comment: If you share a real url and demo login credentials, I could check as well

Comment: Dug a little bit more and your approach led me to a solution to use browser developer tools to copy URL as curl command, then I used some online converter from curl to python, and finally, it worked!